Pyspark Raw object not get updated
@udf(allPageContentSchemaOutput)
def modifyContent(input_data: List[Row]) -> List[Row]:
    modified_data = []
    for row in input_data:
        item_dict = row.asDict()  # Convert Row to dictionary
        components_list = item_dict.get('components', [])
        for component in components_list:
            component = component.asDict()
            if isinstance(component, dict) and 'locale' in component:
                component['locale'] = {
                    'es-us': 'Test',  # Replace with your logic for es-us
                    'en-us': 'Test2'   # Replace with your logic for en-us
                }
        modified_data.append(Row(**item_dict))
    return modified_data 

What I am trying to do is update local attribute.My input data looks lke this
[{"uid":"blt0bbd250f8c97ce90","components":[{"locale":"es-us"}]},{"uid":"blt0bbd250f8c97ce91","components":[{"locale":"es-us"}]}]

This is my output schema format
output_schema = StructType([
    StructField("uid", StringType(), True),
    StructField("components", ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("locale", MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True)
    ])), True)
])

# Define the schema for the output data
allPageContentSchemaOutput = ArrayType(output_schema)

In the ouput schema "locale" : null. Seems like input_data no get modified. Can you help on this how to restructure modifyContent method to modify input_data and refelect in the allPageContentSchemaOutput.
